# Add empty rows to a matrix without a for loop

Tags: r

i want to add `x` empty rows to a matrix. Therefore i am using a `for` loop and `rbind`, but i would like to know if there is a way without using a for loop?

```
  myMatrix<-matrix(ncol=6,nrow=0)
  x<-4
  value<-NA
  for (i in 1:x){
    myMatrix<-rbind(myMatrix,value)
  }
```

Comment: If you initiate the matrix, just do `matrix(ncol=6,nrow=4)`. If you have an existing matrix and you want to add more rows, one option would be `rbind(myMatrix,matrix(ncol=6,nrow=4))`

Comment: many thanks, i was looking for a solution for an existing matrix. I did not know that rbind can also add other matrices to a matrix. Makes perfectly sense.

Comment: Glad I could help. I guess you could just accept Simon's answer to mark your issue as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize an empty matrix you can do it by setting `data=NA` when calling `matrix()`:

```
myMatrix <- matrix(data=NA, ncol=6, nrow=4)
```

This is also the default behavior when not supplying any `data` argument, so the above is equivalent to simply:

```
myMatrix <- matrix(ncol=6, nrow=4)
```

If you instead want to append to empty rows to an existing matrix you can initialize an empty matrix and append it using `rbind`:

```
newMatrix <- rbind(myMatrix, matrix(data=NA, ncol=6, nrow=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you create a matrix without rows, and then add rows filled with "NA" manually. If you create a matrix with the number of rows you already specify right from the start, it is automatically filled with NAs.

```
x <- 4
m <- matrix(ncol=6,nrow=x)
```